Light fixture changed and now hallway lights not working
I have changed my light fixture in the hallway and all the lights were working fine. Now I have changed the light fixture in my room which has 4 red wires (one is actually live) and 4 black wires (one is the switch live) and neutral lights. There is only one light switch. So I’ve wired it up and it’s working, all the lights downstairs are working except for the hallway lights. What should I do?
this is the old wiring before I changed it in my bedroom

this is the new lighting


The picture I have attached is the new wiring for the bedroom light

What is that bit of copper wire sticking out? Looks like it goes from the red wires before crossing behind the black wire just left of the white plastic block.

wow ... you did a really bad wiring job ... the bare copper ends should not be exposed ... is this at your house?

You need to have 4 terminals as per the old image.
You have missed a connection and that terminal block is too small or you need to sort the wires so there are 2 or 3 into each side.

Hi, thanks for your response. I added another terminal block which worked fine. It was loose connections which was the issue.
Thanks!
